# Build cmake child project from cmake parent project

Tags: cmake

I have cmake two projects, with project 2 added as a git submodule in project 1.

I would like to build project 2 from project 1.

How can I do this? I tried add_subdirectory, but this is just for adding source directories.
I want to use the project 2 cmake files to build it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the ExternalProject module.