# How to configure cmake to add and build sub project which is another project from svn?

Tags: svn, cmake

How to configure cmake to add and build sub project which is another project from svn? Currently we are using svn external which I don't like it.

Comment: There are many questions on this topic on SO. E.g. that one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21894786/build-cmake-child-project-from-cmake-parent-project

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to look at CMake's ExternalProject module:

http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/module/ExternalProject.html

It should provide the capabilities you are looking for.